# Debian VM doesn’t boot on QEMU with "console=hvc0" kernel parameter

Tags: linux, qemu, serial-console, getty

I’m running virtual linux machine (debian12) on QEMU with `-device virtconsole` argument. That argument adds **/dev/hvcX** device nodes to VM. QEMU can connect that device to unix socket on host. If i pass “console=hvc0” parameter to VM’s kernel i get console on host socket and can launch tty on it. However it works only if i configure alongside another one console kernel parameter, e.g. `console=ttyAMA0 console=hvc0`. The problem is that VM doesn’t boot with single `console=hvc0` kernel parameter. Am i missing something?
The whole QEMU command:

```
qemu-system-aarch64 \
-M virt,accel=hvf,highmem=off \
-cpu host \
-smp 2 \
-m 2048 \
-display none \
-daemonize \
-monitor unix:/tmp/qemu-monitor-socket,server=on,wait=off \
-device virtio-serial-pci \
-chardev socket,path=/tmp/qemu-guest-tty,server=on,wait=off,id=guest-tty \
-device virtconsole,chardev=guest-tty \
-device virtio-net-pci,netdev=mynet0,mac=52:54:00:08:06:8b \
-netdev user,id=mynet0,hostfwd=tcp::22221-:22 \
-device virtio-blk-pci,drive=hda \
-drive file=~/qemu/debian/1-debian-12-genericcloud-arm64.qcow2,format=qcow2,discard=unmap,id=hda,if=none \
-cdrom ~/qemu/cloud-init/cloud-init.iso \
-kernel ~/qemu/debian/vmlinuz-6.1.0-9-cloud-arm64 \
-initrd ~/qemu/debian/initrd.img-6.1.0-9-cloud-arm64 \
-append 'root=/dev/vda1 ds=nocloud;h=debian1 console=hvc0'
```

UPD: Problem existing only in Debian. I've tested Ubuntu, Fedora and openSUSE - they boot normally with `hvc0` configured as the only console. All distributions i've tested were latest "cloud" ARM64 images. I've tried debian-12-genericcloud and debian-11-genericcloud images with same result.

Comment: Can you try poping into GRUB and replace `console=ttyAMA0` by `console=hvc0` and see what it does?

Comment: @NicolasFormichella Sadly it's the very problem i face: when i configure single console `hvc0` it doesn't boot, but when configure `ttyAMA0` **AND** `hvc0` together - it boots normally. Btw, i dont use GRUB, i boot directly to kernel and specify kernel parameters by `-append` argument in QEMU command. Do you think i should try with GRUB?

Comment: Tried to boot with GRUB - it works. However `/sys/class/tty/console/active` contains both consoles `ttyAMA0 hvc0` and `/proc/cmdline` contains `BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-10-cloud-arm64 root=UUID=104c538b-bea1-443e-b4b1-95cc2068706f ro console=hvc0`. Despite kernel parameters contain only single console argument, **ttyAMA0** activated by default anyway. Result is the same if i’d use direct kernel boot with `-append 'root=UUID=104c538b-bea1-443e-b4b1-95cc2068706f console=ttyAMA0 console=hvc0'` argument in QEMU command.

Comment: Nevertheless one of the goals was to get getty on **hvc0**. In theory systemd has to start getty on console specified in kernel parameters. Furthermore, i was surprised to know, that systemd has to spawn getty on the first special VM console like **/dev/hvc0** when it's available, even if it wasn't configured in kernel parameters. Unfortunately it doesn't work in Debian. I tested Fedora - it works as expected: if hvc0 is present **serial-getty@hvc0.service** started automatically.

Comment: I've tested Ubuntu and openSUSE as well - works like a charm. If **/dev/hvc0** is presented in system - systemd starts **serial-getty** on it. And if i configure **hvc0** as only console argument in kernel parameters - `/sys/class/tty/console/active` contains only `hvc0` without `ttyAMA0` or other tty. As a result i get kernel messages AND getty on **hvc0**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debian(12) builds its kernels with `CONFIG_VIRTIO_CONSOLE` set to 'm' as opposed to 'y'. This means that your initrd needs to contain the `virtio_console` module in order for hvc0 to be available early enough in the booting process. You can verify if your initrd has the required module by running this command:

```
$ lsinitramfs `readlink -f /boot/initrd.img` | grep virtio_console
usr/lib/modules/6.1.0-11-arm64/kernel/drivers/char/virtio_console.ko
```

If you don't see the module, edit your `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules` file and add a line that says "virtio_console". Then run `update-initramfs -k all -u` as root. Your initrd should now contain the virtio_console module, and when you reboot, systemd will automatically start serial-getty@hvc0.service.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! serial-getty@hvc0 has started. And if i configure hvc0 as last console (after ttyAMA0 for example) in kernel parameters i get boot messages on it. However if configure hvc0 as only console in kernel parameters (without ttyAMA0 or any another console) VM still doesn't boot. Any ideas what am i missing?

Comment: I too have noticed that behavior in the past, and my theory is if you use a kernel with CONFIG_VIRTIO_CONSOLE set to 'y' (not 'm'), passing just hvc0 should work. I never went through the effort of rebuilding the kernel though, since the workaround of passing both was easy enough.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I solved my problem actually. It's just curiosity at this point